# Get value of column content by row with Python/Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, python-3.7

I have identified the row numbers of where I need to get within my excel file, with python pandas; using the below:

```
 row_numberd1 = df[df['Member Name'].str.contains(NameUp)].index.min()
 row_numberd12 = df[df['Member Address Line 3'].str.contains(Zip)].index.min()
```

*i.e.* when I print, the row numbers display:

```
 print(row_numberd1)
 print(row_numberd12)
```

**Now, I am simply wondering how I can use the row number; to get a different columns value. So, get columns value by row number.**

So, for instance, in the below sample:

```
   Age      City
1   34    Sydney
2   30     Delhi
3   16  New York
```

**How could I use the row number**; *i.e.* let's say `Row 3`, Column '`City`' to get the '`New York`' value?

Comment: It is unclear to me

Comment: Can you create a [MCVE] ?

Comment: df.loc[idx,'columns']

Answer (score 4):

#### `.loc` for **label** based indexing

```
df.loc[3, 'City']
#'New_York'

# For a single value use `.at`
df.at[3, 'City']
#'New_York'
```

---

#### `iloc` for **index** based selection

```
df.iloc[2, 1]
#'New_York'

# For a single value use `.iat`
df.iat[2, 1]
#'New_York'
```

---

#### `iloc` + `get_loc` for a combination of both

(i.e. 3rd value in 'City')

```
df.iloc[2, df.columns.get_loc('City')]
#'New_York'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use
`df[column_name][row_number]`

Comment: This is called ["chained indexing"](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) and should be avoided.